# Google Spreadsheet creates Google Calendar Event

Tags: google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am trying to make a website with reservations and using google calendar to do this. The problem is that an embedded google calendar is only for display you cannot click on the time slots. So upon research I found you can use a google spreadsheet to link to a google calendar to input the events. I am struggling with doing so and was wondering if anyone has done this in the past or if someone could give me some help. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This isn't quite the right forum for your question, but I did write a script recently that syncs a Google spreadsheet with Google Calendar: https://github.com/Davepar/gcalendarsync

Comment: Thank you. I am giving this a try. Is there a way to make it feed off of a google form?

Comment: It works and sends it to the calendar. My question is whenever i hit sync it runs through every row. Is there a way to make it just run on new entries that it hasn't scheduled already? And what kind of triggers would I need to setup to have the calendar sync run automatically when a new entry is inputted

Comment: Looks like you can run the sync script using the [form submit event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit). The script doesn't currently have the ability to ignore rows, but a column could be added like "added to Calendar".

Comment: So does that mean whenever it syncs to calendar it goes through all the rows and not just the new rows? That would be a problem with re entering the events wouldnt it?

Comment: Correct, it goes through all events. It uses the "ID" column to make sure events aren't added more than once.

Comment: So does that mean if two events have the same id but one was already scheduled but the other wasn't it would ignore the second one? Or would it realize that it is  different event? And whenever it runs does it only show a popup if there isn't an id? In other words how does it know when to stop?

Comment: Also have you gotten the form submit trigger to run the function? I have it set for form submit and another one for time driven and neither seem to set off the synccalendar function